# timer increase upto 3 after then set to 0 for always

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var times = 0;
$(selector).on('click',function(){
    times += 1;
    if(times > 3){
        times = 0
    }
    console.log(times);
});
```

This will log:

```
1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,and so on ...
```

But I want to get the result like this:

```
1,2,3,0,0,0,0, ..... , 0
```

It means after the number `3` the times variable should always be `0`.

How should I do that?

Comment: use a flag to determine when that happens.

Comment: I've tried with a flag, but if the user click repeatedly and right after again the click function would be called.

Comment: or you could unbind from the event.

Comment: NO. That's what I can't do.

Comment: Isn't there anyway to set it 0 for always??

Comment: not with out throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another one:

```
var times = 1;
$(function(){
$("#test").on('click',function(){ 
  console.log(times);
  if(times >= 3 || times == 0){
    times = -1
  }
  times += 1;        
});
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/q1ywowm1/1/

Comment: This one is brilliant :)

Comment: Not so brilliant considering it is unnecessarily changing the precondition on `times`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var times = 0;
var canClick = true;
$("#test").on('click',function(){

    if ((times <= 3) && (canClick == true)) times += 1;

    if (times == 4){

        canClick = false;  
        times = 0

    } 
    console.log(times);
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0b9ovztf/1/

Comment: almost there - you shouldn't increment unless `canClick` is true.

Comment: @DanielA.White ohh so stupid mistake :) Thank you for pointing! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var times = 0, n;
    $('button').on('click',function(){
        n = times++;
        if(times > 4){
           n = 0;
        }
        $(this).text(n);
        console.log(n);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>increment</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as easy as including everything in the conditional `if`:

```
var times = 0;
$(selector).on('click',function(){
    if(times < 3){
        times++;
    }
    else{
        times = 0;
        $(this).off('click');
    }
    console.log(times);
});
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ffebLqzs/

Comment: I didn't know you want to reset it to 0 again. In that case, an else block should take care of it.

Comment: yeah, you're right. But that increase again with +1

Comment: Ok, I updated my question to meet your new requirements and also I build a fiddle for demonstration. Check it out.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal then use one of the many answers with a new variable and other approaches that people have answered here. You won't have any issue with this matter :)

Comment: I'm testing one bye one. And which would be suitable for my case I would accept that.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
var do_count = true, times = 0;
$(selector).on('click',function(){
  if (do_count) {
    times += 1;
    if (times > 3) {
      times = 0;
      do_count = false;
    }
  }
  console.log(times);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a flag `hitzero` defaulted to `false`, make it `true` when `times` hits zero, when you increment the `times`, make sure you increment it only when `hitzero` is `false`

Here is a working demo : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bhubwL4v/)

Here is the code:

```
var times = 1;
var hitzero=false;
$(function(){
$("#test").on('click',function(){ 
    if(hitzero==false)
        times += 1;
    if(times > 3){
        times = 0
        hitzero=true;
    }
    alert(times);     
});
});
```